# How to make link under the names while posting a message on the facebook wall using via my app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am able to post message on the user's facebook wall page using my facebook app but not able to create the link under that user name.

```
message : "@[fb_id] has invited @[fb_id] to play "xxxx" game.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: urrrgh i hate receiving these

Comment: @[fb_id] should be impossible, you may try to use open graph API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/ to publish story.